# How to see all of top x% this year / quarter / month / week / overall?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation-leagues

When we visit any users profile we see a badge saying like **top 5% this month** beside his name. For different user it shows different time frame. I think it shows the one for which the user has best position. This behavior is understandable.

But sometimes being in top 6% allover is better than being in top 5% in an year or month. Same comparison can be between year & month, month & week and so on. So, when someone (or myself) is viewing my profile and trying to understand my total position instead of week / month position, he can't do so, because I have a better position in week / month than overall / year. I think this is important when we are connecting our profiles with careers.stackexchange.com. But I cannot find a way to do so.

So, is there actually any way, by which we can just see my / any users's all positions with one click? (I understand I can figure it out by visiting the league pages and doing the math myself to get my position in each time frame. But that's not what I would like to do every time I want to know about my position or any other person's position in any specific time frame).

> If there is no existing way for this, I would suggest to show it as a popover for the currently shown badge which can be displayed on hover or click.

Comment: Note that I wrote [a script to calculate percentages automatically in the leaderboards](http://stackapps.com/questions/6485/show-each-users-percentile-in-rep-leagues). Also, it might be better in some respects to just adjust the heuristics so that the default displayed percentile is weighted toward favoring even slightly larger numbers over longer periods by some proportion.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Agreed. But setting the proper weights for those will be a difficult thing, I think. Instead of that if possible, the user may choose which position to show in their own profile.